# Issue with prism.js and jade

Tags: pug, prism.js

I am trying to highlight syntax with prism.js and having troubles when it comes to markup. I know it is linked and working properly because my sass is being highlighted correctly but then I try to highlight jade and it has no impact.

Here is my code:

```
h3 Sass
div.source(id="panel")
  pre
    code.language-scss.
      figure {
      width: 80%;
      }

      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
h3 Jade
div.source(id="panel")
  pre
    code.language-markup.
      figure
        img(src='http://placehold.it/560x420')
        figcaption.
          "Caption text."
```

As I said, the sass portion shows up correctly so I know that's working but the jade does not. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use **`code.language-pug`** instead of `code.language-markup`. This is because Prism doesn't include Pug/Jade in markup.